# Submit(); not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

> jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".sendcomment").keydown(function(a) {
    if (a.keyCode == 13) {
       var that = $(this).attr("id");
       var t = that.substr(9);
       var e = "#"+t;
       $(e).submit();
       return false;
    }

        });
});
```

> Form:

```
<form class="commentform" id="849" accept-charset="UTF-8"> 
<input type="hidden" name="comment_publication_id" id="comment_publication_id" value="849" autocomplete="off">
<textarea name="comment" id="commentto849" class="sendcomment" placeholder="Escreva seu comentário" title="Escreva um comentário para esta publicação" required=""></textarea>  
</form>
```

The from takes  multiple data in Mysql having the same form multiple times with different ID's.

I tested the code in other page without mysql data (only 1 form) and guess what? worked.

Comment: Worked? So what's the problem?

Comment: I don't think you can use numbers in form ID. ID cannot start with a number, as far as I know. https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Comment: alert(t); to see what substring you're passing for an id

Comment: The problem is simple: nothing happens '-'

Comment: @MarleneOliveira try putting a letter character at the beginning of the `849` id of the form, like `id="f849"`, update your javascript to look that up and then see if it works for you.

Comment: I'll leave it up to @Zealander to write up the answer if he/she wants, it was their idea :)

Comment: No probs, simple solution. I've hit that annoying problem myself a couple of times.

Comment: haha, is the life my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using something more clean to find the id of the form you want to submit than "commentto849" ?

Add a `data-submit="849"` attribute to your textarea and get it with `$(this).data("submit")`

I think your code to extract the id of the form is error-prone.

The final result would be like this :

```js
$(function() {
  $(".sendcomment").keydown(function(a) {
    if (a.keyCode == 13) {
      var e = "#" + $(this).data("submit");
      $(e).submit();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form class="commentform" id="form849" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="comment_publication_id" id="comment_publication_id" value="849" autocomplete="off">
  <textarea name="comment" id="commentto849" data-submit="form849" class="sendcomment" placeholder="Escreva seu comentário" title="Escreva um comentário para esta publicação" required=""></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: nothing happens, this worked> @MarleneOliveira try putting a letter character at the beginning of the 849 id of the form, like id="f849", update your javascript to look that up and then see if it works for you. –  watcher 4 mins ago

Comment: Oh yes and as @Zealander pointed out. In the official (HTML4) specifications an ID attribute must start with a letter THEN can have digits. IN HTML5 you can have a number as ID

Comment: @MarleneOliveira . What version of HTML are you using ? If it's HTML4 you have to put a letter at beginning otherwise not .. I will add it for clarity

Comment: But I guess @Zealander should claim the points if he wants :) He thought it first ..

Comment: But I have to say that if you use HTML5 you don't need to put a letter as first character thou !

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

> I don't think you can use numbers in form ID. **ID cannot start with a number**, as far as I know. css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number –  Zealander 17 mins ago

thanks!

Comment: For HTML 4, the answer is technically:

ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

HTML 5 is even more permissive, saying only that an id must contain at least one character and may not contain any space characters.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$(e)[0].submit();
```

insted

```
$(e).submit();
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].submit is not a function